# typescript jwt.verify cannot access data

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt

I'm trying to use JWT with nodejs.
My problem is that I can't read the data from the JWT verify function.
I'm using it like this :

```
//encode when logging in
const token = jwt.sign(
    { user: user },
    'secret'
);


// decode when fetching the user from token
const decoded = jwt.verify(req.body.jwtToken, 'secret');
    return res.send({
         user: decoded.user // <-- error here
    });
```

Here are the typings for the verify method:

```
export declare function verify(
   token: string,
   secretOrPublicKey: string | Buffer,
): object | string;
```

linter Error is :

```
Property user does not exists on typeof "object|string".
```

How am I supposed to get the data from the decoded token?

[Link to the documentation of the library](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken)

Comment: Please add the name of the jwt-library you are using.

Comment: I added it to the description

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When using Typescript, you have to remember everything is typed as in e.g. Java or C#. 
`object` is a superclass that has no knowledge of the property `user`.

While this code is valid in javascript (you are looking at javascript documentation), it is not in typescript.

To fix this error, cast the decoded token using `any`.

```
return res.send({
    user: (<any>decoded).user
});
```

Comment: Thanks! And if deny 'any', specify type: 
(<{email: string}>extractedToken).email

Comment: Although my approach works well and does so without any effort, I advice you to use the one that Radu Diță provided. Even if it means a bit more work, it can eliminate writing bugs in the long end.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle sorry for downvoting it. But using <any> is not the greatest solution :)

Comment: @sunnyarya that's indeed what I was saying in my comments. There are better ways but they take extra efforts

Comment: whats the point of typescript if we use 'any'? the solution from Radu Diță is show how it should be used. but of course any will work depending on tsconfig

Comment: @AppySharma please read my comments

Answer (score 11):

You need to **cast** the decoded token. Although casting to **any** will work, you'll also lose type checking on that variable.

A more robust approach is to declare an **interface** that captures the structure of your decoded token and cast using it.

```
// token.ts
export interface TokenInterface {
  user: {
     email: string;
     name: string;
     userId: number;
  };
}
```

and then you can cast using

```
decoded as TokenInterface
```

or more exactly in your case

```
return res.send({
   user: (decoded as TokenInterface).user
});
```

Notes:

1. The casting is done at compile time, not runtime
2. Creating an interface has the added benefit that you keep your type definition in one place. This is especially useful if you want to add a field of that particular type to an existing object. An example of this is adding the token as a field on object of the **express.Request** type.

Answer (score 3):

Create a user payload interface

```
interface UserPayload {
  id: string;
}
interface JwtExpPayload {
  expiresIn: string;
  exp: number;
}
```

Cast to UserPaylod

```
 try {
    const jwtPayload = jwt.decode(
      req.header('authorization')!
    ) as JwtExpPayload;

    req.jwtPayload = jwtPayload;

    const payload = jwt.verify(
      req.header('authorization')!,
      process.env.JWT_KEY!
    ) as UserPayload;

    req.currentUser = payload;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

middleware function

```
export const requireAuth = (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  if (req.jwtPayload && Date.now() >= req.jwtPayload!.exp * 1000) {
    throw new TokenExpiredError();
  }
  if (!req.currentUser) {
    throw new NotAuthorizedError();
  }

  next();
};
```

```
 const userJwt = jwt.sign(
    {
      id: existingUser.id,
    },
    process.env.JWT_KEY!,
    { expiresIn: 30 }
  );
```